# Guardar ubicación de Window Form en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una pregunta sobre c# sobre Window Form, quiero guardar la ubicación de mi ventana en el registro de windows para que cuando vuelva abrir el programa vuelva a aparecer en la ultima ubicación donde se cerró con anterioridad, es decir que si muevo la ventana de mi prográma a la esquina izquierda superior y termino su ejecución cuando vulva a ejecutarlo quiero que aparezca en la esquina izquierda superior.

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema?

Comment: Te daré una respuesta igual de bien explicada que tu pregunta: Usa un archivo de configuración.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo q has intentado

Comment: Lo del registro es una idea terrible, yo también te recomiendo un archivo de configuración.

Comment: @bsebe pq dices q lo del registro es una terrible idea, hay muchas aplicaciones q guardan sus configuraciones en el registro

Comment: @Japv Porque el registro hay que mantenerlo. Crear la clave, modificarla y eliminarla cuando se desinstale la aplicación. Si, por cualquier problema corrompes el registro de windows el SO va a romper. Si haces la aplicación en .net core no habrá registro en Linux o Mac. Etc. Hay varios problemas de usarlo que se resuelven usando un archivo de configuración. ¿Qué ganas con almacenar configuración en el registro? Que haya muchas aplicaciones que lo hagan tampoco significa que esté bien. Además que suele ser por motivos de código legacy.

Comment: @bsebe, por otra parte guardar la configuracion en un fichero como dices, hace que quede expuesta a que cualquiera borre el fichero o modifique el contenido del fichero en cambio guardarla en el registro hace que la configuracion no quede expuesta ya que habria q ser mago para saber que clave es, respecto a lo de crear la clave, modificarla y eliminarla, eso hay q saberlo hacer y depende mas de los conocimientos q tenga uno, si sabes trabajar con el registro no va a haber ningun problema, como ves nada es absoluto, todo tiene pros y contra